# Convert string to XML illegal characters

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a string into XML and running into an illegal character issues when the string contains `&` symbol

```
select convert(xml, 
    '<root>
        <stuff>
            <test>something & this will error</test>
        </stuff>
    </root>')
```

> XML parsing: line 3, character 25, illegal name character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand `&` character in XML.  Try replacing the `&` with `&amp;`

```
select convert(xml, 
    REPLACE('<root>
        <stuff>
            <test>something & this will error</test>
        </stuff>
    </root>','&','&amp;'))
```

Comment: And <, >, &, ', " and so on. I am curious how you replace `<` or `>`

Comment: Give example how you replace `<`

Comment: Same idea: use `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>`, etc.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: so result will be **`&lt;root&gt;&lt;stuff and so on...`** No thanks

Comment: No.  You don't have to escape them in the SQL statement...  The other characters are part of the markup.  I assumed by your comment you meant within the entity text.  You don't have to replace any other characters in the example, only the `&`.  If you were going to use those characters between a tag then you would have to escape them.

Comment: Show me the code for example given in string by author. I know how `FOR XML PATH('')` works when used on table. Example :`<root><><><></root>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The code I provided in my answer is for the example given by the author.

Comment: Try to make work this: `select convert(xml, '<root><<<><>>><<>   </root>')` with your approach

Comment: It's the same thing.  Multiple REPLACE statements.  It's the cost of having invalid XML.

Comment: Show me the code, you write in second comment that is matter of simple replace, I want to see how you handle it, invalid XML will cause error during `CONVERT`

Comment: I'm not going to go through this any further in comments.  You can post a new question and tag me in it if you want my solution spelled out explicitly.  Or you can search how to use multiple REPLACE statements in TSQL.

Comment: But one final thing, the XML in your comments is invalid.  You must escape everything in between your `<root></root>` tag in your prior comments.  That's how XML works.

Comment: Never mind, I know exactly how XML works, question is how in TSQL with input `<root><><<<>><&'"</root>` will you escape them using REPLACE to get well-formed XML (of course this example was oversimplified because `<` can be deep inside many nodes.)

Comment: Oh gosh, I see what you're saying now....  Sorry for my ignorance...  Want to delete this comment thread and start over?  Although, escaping the angle brackets is actually outside the scope of this question...

Comment: I will leave this. I am just curious about general approach, maybe I will ask question if malformed XML like I propose is recoverable in pure TSQL.

Comment: My approach would depend on whether or not it's hardcoded or from a table, like you mentioned earlier.  If from a table you can use `FOR XML` and `REPLACE`.  Otherwise it's obviously a bit more involved.

Comment: I will ask I know there may be very creative solution :)